# Type error:Cannot read property 'mv' of undefined

Tags: html, node.js

I want to upload all type of files(ex: csv,html files), im using the below code but it throwing a error called

> "Cannot read property 'mv' of undefined.."

Here is my code,

```
app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {
  if(req.files){
    let  file = req.files.file;
    file.mv('./Emailcsv/'+file,function(err,data){
      if(err){
        return  res.send("error occured")
      }
      else{
        console.log("saved");
        res.send("File uploaded")
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Here is my  html code,

```
<div className="col-md-6" style={{marginTop:30}}>
<p>Hey There, Upload a HTML file here</p>
<form ref='uploadForm'
  id='uploadForm'
  action='/file_upload'
  method='post'
  encType="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="sampleFile" />
    <input type='submit' value='Upload!' />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using `express-upload` package to perform the uploads?

Comment: Can you post the structure of your `req.files` variable?

Comment: i'm using 'express-fileupload'

Comment: @SusmithaPanda  Can you please update your post with your `html` (template) code too?

Comment: I think `req.files` should be an Array. you can print `req.files` and see what are you getting.

Comment: Here is the structure of what i'm getting in console.log(req.files)
  
 { sampleFile: 
   { name: 'VIPPLAN1html',
     data: <Buffer 3c 21 64 6f 63 74 79 70 65 20 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0a 3c 68 74 6d 6c 20 78 6d 6c 6e 73 3d 22 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 77 77 77 2e 77 33 2e 6f 72 67 2f 31 39 39 ... >,
     encoding: '7bit',
     truncated: false,
     mimetype: 'text/html',
     md5: 'f92472c444dcf406d6a05d5979d48e7f',
     mv: [Function] } }

Comment: @SusmithaPanda Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the below line

```
let  file = req.files.file;
```

as,

```
let  file = req.files.sampleFile;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes, it worked .. but file is not saving..showing error occured

Comment: Hope you are hitting the `\file_upload` (REST) endpoint, Can you please check your network panel (in your devtools) and see if the call goes fine (or) it has any descriptive error?

Comment: This is the rest api \file_upload, and it does not contain any descrpitive error.
can you please tell me what is the issue?

Comment: Okay.. Can you please try replacing your `if(err){ return  res.send("error occured") }` block as, `if(err){console.log(err); console.log(data); }` and see what it returns?

Comment: I'm getting this error
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './Emailcsv/[object Object]']
  path: './Emailcsv/[object Object]'

Answer (score 0):

```
Cannot read property 'mv' of undefined..
```

this error is showing because **file** is undefined, `console.log(req.files)`
and see what it contain, then assign value to file
also if you're using multiform, take a look at the [express multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Answer (score 0):

`req.files.file` is of type **UploadedFile**|**UploadedFile[]**, so that means it could be a single file or an array. In this case, if you are sure that you only receive a single file, you can replace the variable declaration with this line:

```
let file = req.files.file as UploadedFile;
```